# Which one of the two codes is more efficient to run on GPU?

Tags: cuda, gpu, opencl

I know, that branching is a bad practice on GPU, if threads take different paths. So, I was thinking how to avoid branching so I came to a certain idea. For example, there is a task needed to be run on GPU:

```
// a takes values either 0 or 1
if(a) b=b+32;
barrier();
```

I can rewrite this code and exclude branching:

```
// a takes values either 0 or 1
b=b+a*32;
```

I know that this example is not realistic, but just as idea, which one of the two ways of writing code would be more efficient on GPU? (In fact, I had practical situations, where I could avoid branching and use the second method).

I didn't really tried anything, but the general understanding will help me to write my code more efficiently later on.

Comment: I have little knowledge in this area, but thought that branching was impossible on GPUs, so have always assumed that `b+a*32` was the normal way to do this

Comment: Your assumption that what you have shown will make the compiler issue a branch isn’t correct on Nvidia hardware. They have predicated execution instructions which allows logical expressions which evaluate non-uniformly across a warp of threads to execute without branching and instruction replay. Just trust the compiler and writing e code naturally. It will do a better job than you 99.9999% of the time

Comment: @MooingDuck well, in OpenCL and CUDA it is possible to do branching.

Comment: @talonmies thanks! I will take this into consideration. Just to recap. Have I understand you correctly, that compilers decide the efficient way to compile your code and in this case the first set of code can be rewritten by the compiler into the second set of code (on the instruction level of course)?

Comment: Not really. I am saying that there are other methods available in the instruction set to avoid branching and the compiler has extremely good idiom analysis to find such cases and emit code that is optimal. It isn’t your optimisation, it is an instruction masking approach, so that threads that don’t need to do anything just do a null op without branching

Answer (score 1):

This kind of optimization is (normaly) done by the compiler. Dont care about it.
The key is very often memory management : coalescent access, avoid to write/read too much in global memory, use smartly shared memory and local store!